# не работает скрипт на openserver

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, openserver

Вот какой мой код

```
<p><input type="email" placeholder="E_mail" name="email" id="email"></p>
<p><input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password"></p>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="<?php captcha_show()?>" name="captcha" id="captcha"></p>
<p>
<button onclick="post_query('gform','register','email.password.captcha')">Регистрация</button>
</p>

function post_query(url, name, data)
 {
var str = '';
$.each(data.split('.'), function (k, v) {
    str += '&' + v + '=' + $('#' + v).val();
});
$.ajax({
    url: '/' + url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: name + '_f=1' + str,
    cache: false,
    success: function (resu){
        var obj = $.parseJSON(resu);
        if (obj.goo) goo(obj.goo);
        else
        alert(obj.massage);
    }
});

}
function goo( url ) {
    window.location.href='/' + url;
}

if($_POST['register_f']){
//captcha_valid();
email_valid();
password_valid();
if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$_POST[email]'"))) massage('Такой Email Уже занят');
// $code = generateRandomString();
// $_SESSION['confirm'] = array(
// 'type' => 'register',
// 'email' => $_POST['email'],
// 'password' => $_POST['password'],
// 'code' => $code,
// );

$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
mysqli_query($CONNECT, 'INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ("","'.$_POST['email'].'","'.$_POST['password'].'", "", 0, '.$ref.',0,'.$today.')');
//goo('info');
```

А вот такая ошибка при нажатии на кнопку. Хотя точно такой код работает на другой кнопке нармально.
Кто знает как исправить это ?

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Function.n.parseJSON (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4)
at Object.success (common.js:13)
at i (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2)
at z (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4)
```

Comment: Вот какой мой код 
<p><input type="email" placeholder="E_mail" name="email" id="email"></p>
<p><input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password"></p>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="<?php captcha_show()?>" name="captcha" id="captcha"></p>
<p>
<button onclick="post_query('gform','register','email.password.captcha')">Регистрация</button>
</p>

Comment: Судя по трассе пришла какая-то невалидная json по аяксу, выведите в консоль что в resu. там должна быть строка json. Добавьте еще в функцию ajax параметр `dataType: "json",`

Comment: Все как было так и осталось возможно проблема связана с сервером ?

Comment: Я ведь попросил вывести то, что пришло с сервера. Выведите и приложите к вопросу, дальше уже будет понятнее

Comment: В том то и дело что ничего не пришло

Comment: Сервер доступен? Хорошо, функция `post_query` была вызвана? А функция `success` вызывалась? И что с самим сервером? Логи ведь должны быть доступны или скрипт для обработки `/gform` Еще к `ajax` помимо `success` добавьте функцию `error` -- может там что будет...

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема заключалась в том что не было скобок {}

```
else if($_POST['register_f']){
email_valid();
password_valid();

if ( mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '".$_POST[email]."'")) )
    massage('Этот E-mail занят');
```

Тут я поставил условие и все заработало. Видимо верхняя часть кода исполняла весь код целиком
    if(1==1) {
        $mails = $_POST['email'];
        $pasw = md5($_POST['password']);
        $pasw2 = $_POST['pas'];
        $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

```
    mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO `users`(`id`,`email`,`password`,`ip`,`protekted`,`ref`,`balance`,`dateregister`)
        VALUES ('','" . $mails . "','" . $pasw . "','','0','" . $_SESSION['id'] . "','500','" . $today . "')");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '".$mails."'") );
    go_auth($row);
    goo('profile');
}
```

}